# SVG pattern element not working in Safari

Tags: vue.js, svg

SVG pattern element not working and Safari but it works in Chrome. Why doesn't the path filled using pattern in Firefox and Safari?
code:

```html
<svg>    
  <path d="example" fill="url(#img)" />
  <pattern id="img">
    <image xlink:href="link" class="img-fluid"  />
  </pattern>
</svg>
```

Comment: Possibly because elsewhere on your page you have a <base> element. That breaks things on Safari. Alternatively Safari might want height and width attributes on the image element.